# Add new topic and/or an section in the center to inform users to what to do when they find a site scraping Stack Exchange content

Tags: feature-request

Currently, we have [the policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers) of using [the contact form](https://anime.stackexchange.com/contact) to report sites scraping our content.

However, if we go to the [contact us](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) page link on the bottom of the page, there is no option under "What can we help you with?" indicating that we can do this, aside from selecting the "Other" option, nor is there a Help Center topic about this: https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=scraping

For an experienced user, this might not be a problem to search meta for this, but this might confuse new users as to what they can do when they find a site scraping content from Stack Exchange. At the very least I would like to request a new topic be added in the contact form about this.

Comment: Has this been a problem for Anime.SE? I was under the impression that the scraper problem was mostly localized to SO and the other tech sites.

Comment: Nothing [too](http://how360.org/anime/) major, just wanted a bit more transparency on what we can do.